# A problem while getting access for hr in sql developer

Tags: oracle

I am a student and I have a project in the oracle database. I am trying to get access in hr schema and I am using cmd to do that, but I have an issue. I want to see the name and the con_id of v$pdbs but when I execute the select command of this table, it shows no value just like that

[image]

Thank you very much for your consideration. I would be very happy if someone helps me with this issue.

Comment: Just as an aside, screen shots of command sessions are very hard to read - even when clicking on them to magnify them.  It's really quite simple to copy the text from the command session and paste it here, then enclose it in 'code' tags.

Answer (score 1):

For a pluggable DB, you need to set the container first in order to alter a user

Check your current container( most probably it would return the `CDB$ROOT` container ) :

```
SQL> SHOW CON_NAME
```

List available containers :

```
SQL> SELECT name,open_mode FROM v$containers;
```

and then set the desired one among listed containers :

```
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER = PDB1;
```

Now you can alter user as you did in the question.